# Adding values to an array at specific indexes containing the data from within the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, spread

My initial Data looks like this:

```
const data = [ 
  {date: "jan.15", video: 2, chat: 1, other: 3}, 
  {date: "jan.16", video: 5, chat: 3, other: 3}
]
```

In order to use this data I had to turn each of these object into an array. So I did this:

```
   const count = data.map((item, idx)=> {
        let value = Object.values(item);
         return value
    }) || [];
```

which output:

```
[
  ["jan.15", 2, 1, 3]
  ["jan.16", 5, 3, 3]
]
```

However I need to add values to these arrays that include the data from the array..
So I need an output of something like this:

```
[
  ["jan.15", 2, "jan.15, 2", 1, "jan.15, 1", 3, "jan.15, 3"],
  ["jan.16", 5,"jan.16, 5", 3,"jan.16, 3", 3, "jan.16, 3"]
]
```

And Im not sure how to read the values and insert them into the array at specific points.

The date ex)`jan.15` is associated with each of the following values in the array. So following each value I need to insert the data+theValue to be used in my application.

Comment: What is the logic behind getting the output? For instance why is the 2 in the string "jan.15, 2"?

Comment: I am working with a library that needs a tooltip value following the value displayed. Jan.15 (the date) is associated with each value following it in the array. So I need to append the date to the number in order to generate my tooltip with the information for each point.

Comment: Quick & dirty: `return [value[0], value[1], value[0]+", "+value[1], value[2], value[0]+", "+value[2], value[3], value[0]+", "+value[3]]`

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the logic needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could `map` over array and then do another `map` on `Object.values`.

```js
const data = [ {date: "jan.15", video: 2, chat: 1, other: 3}, {date: "jan.16", video: 5, chat: 3, other: 3}]

const result = data.map(({ date, ...rest }) => (
  [date].concat(...Object.values(rest).map(v => (
    [v, `${date}, ${v}`]
  )))
))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is some pice of code.
we follow same as your approch `Object.values` to get all values from object, and we reduce it according to your condition.

```js
const data = [ 
  {date: "jan.15", video: 2, chat: 1, other: 3}, 
  {date: "jan.16", video: 5, chat: 3, other: 3}
]

const reducedData = data.reduce((prev, curr, i) => {
    const value = Object.values(curr)
    const newValue = value.reduce((prev, curr, i, arr) => {
      if (i === 0 || i === 1) {
        prev.push(curr);
        if (i === 1) {
          prev.push(arr[0] + ', ' + curr);
        }
        return prev;
      }
      prev.push(curr),
      prev.push(arr[0] + ', ' + curr);
      return prev;
    }, []);
    prev.push(newValue);
    return prev;
}, []);

console.log(reducedData)
```